# Future of Try both recover

Tags: scala

Which way is the best to recover Future[Try[A]] type with type A?

```
val future: Future[String] = ???
val tr: Try[String] = ???

future recover {case _ => "recovered"}
tr recover {case _ => "recovered"}

val futureTry: Future[Try[String]] = ???
```

How to recover both with "recovered" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Try` inside a `Future`, it's a simple matter to move the exception (if it exists) into the exception handling of the `Future`:

```
val futureTry: Future[Try[String]] = ???
futureTry.flatMap {
  case Success(v) ⇒ Future.successful(v)
  case Failure(t) ⇒ Future.failed(t)
}.recover { case _ ⇒ "recovered" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `map` the `Future` to `recover` a `Failure` within it, and then `recover` the `Future` with an instance of `Success`.

```
futureTry.map(_.recover{case _ => "recovered"})
    .recover{case _ => Success("recovered")}
```

`Future[Try[A]]` is redundant though, because `Future` is essentially the same as `Try` with successful and failed states. There isn't much sense in having two layers of success and failure, especially if you're going to recover them to the same default value.